# Ember: prevent link-to from firing when an action within it is clicked

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I have a table where I want users to navigate to specific items when they click a row, but the row may contain other elements (such as checkboxes) that trigger actions but do **not** trigger navigation (think gmail).

My structure is like this:

```
{{#each player in controller}}
  {{#link-to "player" player.uid tagName="tr"}}
    <td>
       {{input action="select" type="checkbox" checked=selected bubbles=false}}
    </td>
    <td>
      {{player.name}}
    </td>
    ...
  {{/link-to}}
{{/each}}
```

My problem is that despise the `bubbles=false` (as indicated in the [spec](http://emberjs.com/guides/templates/actions/#toc_stopping-event-propagation)), the `link-to` fires and a navigate to another route. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That works when you attach an action to an element, the input helper doesn't support `action='foo'` in that manner.  It isn't even being hit at all.

http://emberjs.jsbin.com/lugatite/1/edit

You'll need to roll you're own checkbox, or just observe the checked value in your controller

```
App.MyCheckBox = Ember.Checkbox.extend(Ember.TargetActionSupport, {
    target: Ember.computed.alias('controller'),
    action: 'save',
    actionContext: Ember.computed.alias('context'),
    click: function(el) {
      this.triggerAction(); 
      el.stopPropagation();

    }
});
```

http://jsbin.com/lugatite/5/edit

Comment: This works for attaching actions, but the link-to still fires, see: http://jsbin.com/lugatite/4/edit

Comment: whoops, sorry I got fixated on the fact that you couldn't do it with the default implementation, I updated with an answer that should work for you.