# Ember - actions within link-to blocks

Tags: ember.js

I am building a component in Ember.js which includes a table. Each `tr` in that table is created using `{{#link-to ...}}` so that clicking anywhere on the row will take a user to another route.

However, I'd like to make a `td` element in those rows clickable to open a link in a new window. I'm doing this as an action.

Right now, clicking the proper `td` element will both trigger the `{{#link-to}}` redirect and activate the action on the `td` element as well.

Instead, I'd like a click on the proper `td` element to *only* trigger that element's action, and ignore the `{{#link-to}}` event above. How would I go about doing this?

This is what my code looks like:

```
<table>
  {{#link-to 'widget' widget.id tagName='tr'}}
    <td>Go to link-to</td>
    <td {{action 'sendMail' widget.email}}>Send Email</td>
  {{/link-to}}
</table>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Ember: prevent link-to from firing when an action within it is clicked](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24369237/ember-prevent-link-to-from-firing-when-an-action-within-it-is-clicked)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Look at this twiddle](https://ember-twiddle.com/77562c9b3828821f68d53b827fac6c07?openFiles=controllers.application.js%2C&route=%2Fmy-route) implemented your case.

You need to call event.stopPropagation for that you need to have `event` object, to get it I used `onclick={{action`

```
<table>
  {{#link-to 'my-route' tagName='tr' bubble=false}}
    <td>Go to link-to</td>
    <td onclick={{action 'sendMail' }}>Send Email</td>
  {{/link-to}}
</table>
```

In sendMail, you need to stop event propagation.

```
actions:{
    sendMail(event){
      console.log('sendMail');
      event.stopPropagation();
    }
  }
```

Comment: This worked for me! Thank you! I just want to point out that the `event` parameter is required for this to work. If you have other parameters you need to pass, put "event" last. Also, ensure `event.stopPropagation();` is the last thing in the function.